# How to save a model to database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Hello im trying to save a model to database. I'm just typing in the value of a title to save it because my id is auto increment. I have tried it but it didn't worked. Can anyone help me?

And what urlRoot or url function i need to specify in my Backbone Model? Do I need to specify url of my collection or?

Model:

```
var DocumentUser = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/app_dev.php/user'
});
```

Here is my save function:

```
save: function(method, model, options) {
    this.model = new DocumentUser();
    this.model.save({
        title: $('#title').val()
    }, {
        success: function(model, respose, options) {
            console.log('The model has been saved to the server');
        },
        error: function(model, xhr, options) {
            console.log('Something went wrong while saving the model');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Backbone [model.save([attributes], [options])](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)  to save a model to your database (or alternative persistence layer), by delegating to [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync).

If the model [isNew](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew), the save will be a "`create`" (HTTP `POST`), if the model already exists on the server, the save will be an "`update`" (HTTP `PUT`).

Code:

```
var DocumentUser = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            title: ''
        },
        urlRoot: '/app_dev.php/user'
    }),
    documentUser = new DocumentUser();

documentUser.save({
    title: $('#title').val()
}, {
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('The model has been saved to the server', response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log('Something went wrong while saving the model', response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but what url i need to put in model? Url of my collection with json response of all the models or?